# Vlookup run-time error for dynamic range and another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

I am getting run-time error for Vlook-up formula while using dynamically from activesheet to another sheet i.e Binarysheet, in Binary sheet, my lookup range is A to C column
I need to iterate the for loop and I have to use vlookup inside the for loop

```
Dim wfd As Worksheet
Set wfd = thisworkbook.Sheets("Binarysheet")

For i = 20 To 61
    Cells(2, i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],wfd!$A:$B,2,False)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells(2, i+1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],wfd!$A:$C,3,0)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
   Next
```

Comment: you cannot mix r1c1 and A1 references: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],wfd!C1:C2,2,False)"`

Comment: Furthermore, `wfd` in `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],wfd!$A:$C,3,0)"` does not refer to the variable `wfd`. Use `Binarysheet`

Comment: with both:  `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & wfd.Name & "'!C1:C2,2,False)"`

Comment: A couple of must reads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba

Comment: You are also going to want to add `Step 2` to your For loop, otherwise each loop will overwrite the previous.

Comment: instead of C1:C2, can I make it as variable like Ci:Ci+2 since columns must be dynamic it should be based on variable like i ? @Scott Craner

Comment: There is no harm just doing C1:C65 and only changing the third criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the above comments and advice from the two linked questions, we can simplify the whole thing and load the whole without the need to loop:

```
Dim wfd As Worksheet
Set wfd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Binarysheet")

With ActiveSheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 20), .Cells(lastrow, 61))
    
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'" & wfd.Name & "'!C1:C65,COLUMN(RC),False)"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End With
```

Comment: you are amazing Scott, it really worked, and how we have to know like for name we have to add likewise  '" & wfd.Name & "' any rules are there for these criterias?